# Standard deviation based on group id from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

This relates to one of y previous question. My end goal is to rank items based on the serial variable, which is derived from a standard deviation value for the start and end of the day. To simply summarise, I would like to calculate both of them (start and end day)  and then I would like to mark it with a 1 if the standard deviations are less than 0.5. What is the best way to do this in R?

Rule that i would like to implement in R:

```
=IF(AND(STDEV.S(D2,D3,D4)<0.5,STDEV.P(E2, E3, E4)<0.5),1,0)
```

Sample data structure:

[image]

Sample output:

[image]

Sample data

```
df<-structure(list(serial = c(11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 
11011209, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210), pnum = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Day = c("Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Wed", 
"Thur", "Mo", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur"), Start = c(7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 
9.75, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5), End = c(14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 15.75, 15.75, 
17.75, 14.75, 14.75, 8.75)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(serial = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), pnum = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Day = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), End = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'serial', 'num', create the 'Pattern', by checking the `sd` of 'Start', 'End' columns are less than 0.5 and connect the multiple expressions to a single one with `&`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(serial, pnum) %>% 
    mutate(Pattern = +(sd(Start) < 0.5 & sd(End) < 0.5)) %>%
    ungroup
```

---

Or instead of specifying each column separately, use `if_all`

```
df %>%
    group_by(serial, pnum) %>%
    mutate(Pattern = +(if_all(c(Start, End), ~ sd(.) < 0.5))) %>%
    ungroup
```